# Broken DAG: No module named auth

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I run my program for `apache-airflow` on airflow DAG

And Error :

> Broken DAG: [`/home/muhammad-nursalim/airflow/dags/bigquery_tutorial.py`] No module named auth

Comment: can you share more context? some code?

Comment: I believe you need [`password` package](https://incubator-airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#extra-packages) support `pip-install apache-airflow[password]`, could also be because of  `ldap`